# AWS Ubuntu Server with MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, selenium, ubuntu

I am currently running AWS ubuntu server to run some scrapers and selenium webdriver. I store all the data into MySQL database in the AWS. Is there a way to use my local mySQL workbench to remotely connect to AWS database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  You need to fist give your IP access to the security group that your Mysql EC2 is in.  In the EC2 console, in the row that has your Mysql EC2, you will see a column for security group... click on the security group.  You will then be able to add an entry into the security group's ACL to allow your IP address (the IP address of where the mysql workbench is located) access.  [Here is a link that goes into more details.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html)

Once you have given your IP address access, you can point your workbench to the hostname of the EC2 instance that has mysql on it.